# Замена значения атрибута в результирующей выборке на значение из справочника

Tags: postgresql

Помогите реализовать задачу
Имеется таблица "Реклама". В поле Category приходят данные либо в виде кодов формата IAB.., либо в виде текста.

| ID | Type | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Картинка | Книги |
| 2 | Видео | IAB25 Non-Standard Contenеt |
| 2 | Видео | Социальные сети |
| 2 | Видео | IAB26-1 Illegal Content |
| 2 | Видео | IAB25-3 |

Так же есть таблица "Справочник"

| Code | Name |
| --- | --- |
| IAB25 | Нестандартный контент |
| IAB25-1 | Немодерируемый UGC |
| IAB26 | Незаконный контент |
| IAB26-1 | Незаконный контент |
| IAB25-3 | Нецензурный контент |

Мне необходимо сделать подсчет креативов по каждой категории, но при этом чтобы коды(IAB...) заменялись на значения из справочников. Я пробовал джоинить справочник с таблицей и группировать по кодам, но тогда все что не попадает в справочник имеет значние NULL.

Для большей наглядности.
В поле name значения из справочников. Я делаю группировку и на выходе получаю.
[image: Таблица рекламы сджоинная со справочником]

И вместо тех значений, которые у меня отсутствуют в справочнике получаю NULL.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе хочу получить такой результат, где вместо кодов iab.. будут соответствующие им значения из справочников

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CREATE TABLE content(ID INT, Type VARCHAR(255), Category VARCHAR(255),Category_value VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO content VALUES
(1,'Картинка','IAB25','Купе'),
(2,'Видео','Социальные', ''),
(2,'Видео','IAB25-1','Кабриолет'),
(2,'Видео','Книги',''),
(2,'Видео','IAB25','Купе');
```

как при группировке получить такой результат?

| ID | Type | Category | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Картинка | Купе | 2 |
| 2 | Видео | Социальные | 1 |
| 2 | Видео | Кабриолет | 1 |
| 2 | Видео | Книги | 1 |

а не такой

| ID | Type | Category | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Картинка | IAB25 | 2 |
| 2 | Видео | IAB25-1 | 1 |
| 2 | Видео | Книги | 1 |
| 2 | Видео | Социальные | 1 |

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приложил скрины. Может быть так будет более понятно

Comment: Вместо скринов нужно добавить в вопрос структуру в виде DML (т.е `CREATE TABLE ...`) и пример данных (в виде `INSERT INTO ...`). Туда нужно включить минимум колонок и данных для демонстрации проблемы. Также для указанных данных нужно задать параметры запроса (если есть) и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: постарался указать все как вы просили